# get_iplayer RTMP failure

Tags: rtmp

Could anyone tell me how to get around this problem highlighted?
I have got no problem downloading subtitles, yet with downloading programmes.

I've used UKBestVPN services. Downloading subtitles no problem so it shouldn't be any problem with the VPN service. Some said I needed to set up port 10060 in Win 7. I did in the Firewall Advanced Setting but the error occurred again.

Thank you.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer>get_iplayer --pid b01fkbb3
get_iplayer v2.80, Copyright (C) 2008-2010 Phil Lewis
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details use --warranty.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain
conditions; use --conditions for details.

INFO Trying to stream pid using type tv
INFO: pid found in cache
Matches:
524: Newsnight - 02/04/2012, BBC Two, News,TV, default,

INFO: 1 Matching Programmes
INFO: Checking existence of default version
INFO: flashhigh1,flashhigh2,flashstd1,flashstd2 modes will be tried for version default
INFO: Trying flashhigh1 mode to record tv: Newsnight - 02/04/2012
INFO: File name prefix = Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default
RTMPDump 2.4 git-6230845 2011-9-25
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10060 (Unknown error)
INFO: Command exit code 3 (raw code = 768)
WARNING: Failed to stream file C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\iPlayer Recordings\Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default.partial.mp4.flv via RTMP
INFO: skipping flashhigh1 mode
INFO: Trying flashhigh2 mode to record tv: Newsnight - 02/04/2012
INFO: File name prefix = Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default
RTMPDump 2.4 git-6230845 2011-9-25
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10060 (Unknown error)
INFO: Command exit code 3 (raw code = 768)
WARNING: Failed to stream file C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\iPlayer Recordings\Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default.partial.mp4.flv via RTMP
INFO: skipping flashhigh2 mode
INFO: Trying flashstd1 mode to record tv: Newsnight - 02/04/2012
INFO: File name prefix = Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default
RTMPDump 2.4 git-6230845 2011-9-25
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10060 (Unknown error)
INFO: Command exit code 3 (raw code = 768)
WARNING: Failed to stream file C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\iPlayer Recordings\Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default.partial.mp4.flv via RTMP
INFO: skipping flashstd1 mode
INFO: Trying flashstd2 mode to record tv: Newsnight - 02/04/2012
INFO: File name prefix = Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default
RTMPDump 2.4 git-6230845 2011-9-25
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10060 (Unknown error)
INFO: Command exit code 3 (raw code = 768)
WARNING: Failed to stream file C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\iPlayer Recordings\Newsnight_-_02_04_2012_b01fkbb3_default.partial.mp4.flv via RTMP
INFO: skipping flashstd2 mode
ERROR: Failed to record 'Newsnight - 02/04/2012 (b01fkbb3)'

C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Expat Shield or any other program that provides a UK IP address.
Get_iPlayer will do the download job.
No RTMP error, then.
UKBestVPN may not be as stable to bypass the IP restriction as Expat Shield is.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume from a successful download of the subtitle file that the video server will play nice with your VPN. I'm fairly certain that the .srt is delivered by a BBC server, while the video stream is served by one of the big CDNs.

Make another attempt with

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer>get_iplayer --pid b01fkbb3 --verbose --long**

and take a look at the results. If it looks like the request for the subtitle file is made to a different domain than the request for the video stream, your most likely issue is that Limelight or Akamai is rejecting requests made through UKBestVPN.

Paid VPN's are typically under no obligation to provide you with a new IP if the CDNs get wise to circumvention of geographical restrictions--but it never hurts to ask. Sorry that's probably not what you wanted to hear; there might be more benign reasons the for the video server to reject your request...maybe if your VPN was really busy, it could have been slow to respond to RTMP handshake...etc.

P.S. Assuming you rectify your issues, here's a couple of tips:

1. Go into **C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer** and make a copy of **get_iplayer.cmd**; paste it back into the program folder and rename it **bbc.cmd**.

> Now all you have to type is **bbc -g horizon**.
>
> Create a user variable called **PATH** and put **C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer** in it.

> Now you can just hit your **Windows key** and type **bbc -g horizon** directly into the ***Search programs and files*** box.

You don't have to deal with text wrap in a puny command-line window.

> Right-click on the get_iplayer icon and select **properties**; click on the **Layout** tab and you can resize it to something more usable.

Comment: With another attempt of "verbose", the same error throws (RTMP failure 10060).  
Have not tried your P.S. tips.

Comment: With the help of Expat Shield (one of the service provider of a UK proxy assigning a UK IP address), get_iplayer does not throw the RTMP failure error message. Download success.

Comment: Installed ExpatShield - adware, with restrictions - and even this refused to connect. The PC has no antivirus and firewall off. Whatever I try, no luck getting get_iplayer to work. Watching the programmes online through a VPN works fine though. So, there must be a major flaw in get_iplayer.